# OSGeo4W Network Installer for several version of QGIS

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

I want install several versions of QGIS with OSGeo4W Network Installer (2.18, 3.0 and master).
Will it be good if I install it in one root direction or should I create separate folders?

Comment: I am right now in the same step you are. Did you go any further from Feb till now?
Greetings,

Comment: [@Hugo Herrador](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/128518/hugo-herrador), please ask it as a new question if you require certain assistance through GIS SE [Ask a question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Otherwise, you are welcomed to leave a comment on the question because what you have now is not a proper answer to the initial question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146649)